# Сортировка массива на JS по тексту внутри UL>LI с инпутом

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Есть входной массив вида:

```
var array = [
    '<li><input type="radio" name="cityRadio" value="123|Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</li>',
    '<li><input type="radio" name="cityRadio" value="456|Москва">Москва</li>',
    '<li><input type="radio" name="cityRadio" value="789|Киев">Киев</li>'
];
```

Нужно отсортировать его по названиям городов, чтобы первым ишел UL>LI с городом Киев, потом Москва, потом Питер. Пробовал так:

```
array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.match(/(.*)<\/li>/) - b.match(/(.*)<\/li>/);
});
```

но не сортуется, не силен в регулярках

Comment: а невозможно отсортировать его до формирования верстки?

Comment: Я бы тогда не задавал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [
  '<li><input type="radio" name="cityRadio" value="123|Санкт-Петербург">Санкт-Петербург</li>',
  '<li><input type="radio" name="cityRadio" value="456|Москва">Москва</li>',
  '<li><input type="radio" name="cityRadio" value="789|Киев">Киев</li>'
]

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a.replace(/<\/?[^>]*>/g, '')
  b = b.replace(/<\/?[^>]*>/g, '')

  return a > b
});

console.log(array)
```